# How to schedule a local location triggered notification that only appears on a certain day in swift

Tags: swift, notifications

I would like to schedule a notification to appear on a specified day if the user leaves a specified location.

A UNLocationNotificationTrigger handles the location trigger aspect.
A UNCalendarNotificationTrigger handles the date trigger aspect.

However, when requesting the notification as shown below, you can only pass one trigger.

```
UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Is it possible to achieve this type of notification? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You could just create two UNNotificationRequests. I guess it's up to the app to manage those two and let them appear to be one use case.

Comment: Wouldn’t that be an “OR”? If it is that date _or_ in that location?